# Поиск по необязательным полям

Tags: php, sql, yii2

У меня есть поля в бд: one,two,three,four,five,six
Обязательные для заполнения: two,three,four
Вопрос, как мне проверять, заполнено ли поле one, five и six? и искать потом если заполнено one с $model->one и т.д.

Пытался делать так, но так не работает, если поле не заполнено one например, то ничего не ищет:

```
 $v = Feedauto::find()
   ->andWhere(['two' => $model->two])
   ->andWhere(['three' => $model->three])
   ->andWhere(['four' => $model->four])
   ->andFilterWhere(['or',['region'=>null],['region' => $model->region_id]])
   ->andFilterWhere(['or',['one'=>null],['one' => $model->one]])
   ->andFilterWhere(['or',['five'=> null],['five' => $model->five]])
   ->andFilterWhere(['or',['six'=> null], ['six' => $model->six]])
   ->all();
```

Надеюсь меня поняли))
т.е. проверка, если поле пустое, не искать по нему, если заполнено, то искать по нему...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если для необязательных полей по умолчанию записывается пустая строка ка значение, то запрос должен быть таким:

```
$v = Feedauto::find()
->andWhere(['two' => $model->two])
->andWhere(['three' => $model->three])
->andWhere(['four' => $model->four])
->andFilterWhere(['or',['region' => ''],['region' => $model->region_id]])
->andFilterWhere(['or',['one' => ''],['one' => $model->one]])
->andFilterWhere(['or',['five' => ''],['five' => $model->five]])
->andFilterWhere(['or',['six' => ''], ['six' => $model->six]])
->all();
```

Comment: Данные в $model есть, 100%. Данных модели Feedauto может не быть... и вот если их нет, то не искать в полях one, five и т.д.

Comment: тогда вариант который вы описали в вопросе

Comment: он не работает...

Comment: Можете сдампить итоговый запрос, чтобы проверить?

Comment: дополнил вопрос, посмотрите, что внизу написал

Comment: не результат запроса, а сам sql-ный запрос

Comment: SELECT * FROM `feedauto` WHERE (`two`='2') AND (`three`='2') AND (`four`='2') AND (`one`='a') AND (`five`='a') AND (`six`='a') AND (`region`='22')

Comment: По необязательных полях у вас должна быть конструкция ` ... AND (five is NULL OR five = 'a') AND ...`

Comment: да, но ее почемуто нет....

Comment: Что за фреймворк или библиотеку для построения запросов вы используете?

Comment: yii2. всмысле какую библиотеку? это стандартные методы в yii2

Comment: не увидил тег yii. `->andFilterWhere(['or', 'region IS NULL', ['region' => $model->region_id]])`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `feedauto` WHERE (`two`='2') AND (`three`='2') AND (`four`='2') AND ((region IS NULL) OR (`region`='22')) AND ((one IS NULL) OR (`one`='a')) AND ((five IS NULL) OR (`five`='a')) AND ((six IS NULL) OR (`six`='a'))   это возвращается, но var_dump все равно array(0) { }

Comment: https://c2n.me/3WzRuey   вот заполнена таблица...

Comment: в необязательных полях `NULL` или все таки записывается `''` (пустая строка)?

Comment: там ничего не записывается, по идеи ' '

Comment: Внес изменения в свой ответ

Comment: я тоже так делал, но так возвращает запрос:  
SELECT * FROM `feedauto` WHERE (`two`='2') AND (`three`='2') AND (`four`='2') AND (`region`='22') AND (`one`='a') AND (`five`='a') AND (`six`='a')

Comment: https://c2n.me/3WzSZ87  сделал так, но ошибка та же..

Comment: Спасибо, помогли